# Combinations of a matrix

Tags: permutation

I want to compute all combinations of a given matrix.

I came up with

```
Clear[fun]
fun[mat_] := 
 Outer[List, Apply[Range, {First@mat[[1]], Last@mat[[1]]}], 
  Apply[Range, {First@mat[[2]], Last@mat[[2]]}]]
```

for a matrix with two rows. Now I want to generalize this function for a matrix with more than two sublists. But I am facing some difficulties with specifying the arguments in `Outer` correctly (I don't want to rewrite `Apply[Range, {First@mat[[1]], Last@mat[[1]]` again and again).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure whether this is what you look for. Both variants should work equally well.

```
fun2[mat_] := Outer[List, Sequence @@ Range @@@ mat[[All, {1, -1}]], 1];
fun3[mat_] := Outer[List, ##, 1] & @@ Range @@@ mat[[All, {1, -1}]];
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for. Somehow didn't get it together with the different `Apply`s. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.